# How to tag/label commits of the same kind (e.g. bugfix, release, etc.) in git?

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to tag/lable/mark git commit of the same kind. For example when working on a new version typically multiple commits are added/created until the new version is finally released.

I know that I can create a **tag** to mark this commit for example as `v1.2.3`. However, this would be a specific tag for this specific commit which is not meant to be re-used on other commits. I am looking for a possibility to tag/label/mark all release commit with a common manner which and than use some command like `show all release commits`, `show all bugfixes`, `show all new_feature_added`, etc.

Currently I simply use the commit message to achieve this, e.g. `New feature: Added xyz` or `BugFix: Fixed xyz`. However, this is not the ideal.

Is this possible in git?

Comment: There are many different styles but this one https://www.conventionalcommits.org/ seems to be winning. Choose one style and always use it.

Answer (score 2):

Git tags, as you noted, are not meant to be shared across different commits, contrary to the common expected semantic of *tags* in other tools. Git tags are basically alias pointer to a specific commit.

You can use [git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) for the purpose you mentioned.

You can use something like: `git log --show-notes=bugfixes` to show all commits matching the note `bugfixes`